# maven dependency error in jira plugin project

Tags: java, maven, jira, pom.xml, jira-plugin

My jira plugin project was working fine. I have executed "atlas-clean" as changes was not reflecting in JIRA.
Now, when i execute - atlas-run then it gives me dependency errors as below:

```
org.apache.http does not exists.
org.apache.http.client does not exists.
org.apache.http.client does not exists.
org.apache.http.client.methods does not exists.
.....
```

In pom.xml, its already existed..

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any idea.. how it could resolve ?

Comment: You have added the dependency in test scope, if the dependecy is needed in other than test phase you have to change the scope.

Comment: Thanks, that was the cause, it resolved the issue. plz add as comment so, i can mark the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the dependency in test scope, if the dependecy is needed in other than test phase you have to change the scope